# How to delay the execution of a function in c#

Tags: c#, timer

In my application, I need to delay the execution of a method for some time. For that I have used System.Windows.Forms.Timer.

I have used the below code to initialize and start the timer.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
timer.Interval = 3000;
timer.Start();
```

In the Timer.Tick event I have called the method which should be delayed as given below.

```
 private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

This works perfectly, but I don't know whether it is the exact method to delay the execution.

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: There are many possible ways to delay execution of some code. Which is best depends on context, which you haven't provided. The marked duplicate will provide some insight regarding comparison of blocking a thread (e.g. with `Thread.Sleep()`) and using some form of asynchronous signaling/callback (e.g. with one of the several timer classes .NET offers). A modern C# idiom not addressed in the duplicate would be to use an `async` method and `await Task.Delay(...)`.

Comment: See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705535/how-to-delay-program-for-a-certain-number-of-milliseconds-or-until-a-key-is-pre and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963465/how-to-call-a-method-after-so-many-seconds

Answer (score 0):

you could start a task and delay, however, the way you are doing it, you will get a callback on your UI thread so you can interact with windows forms ok if that's what your delayed function does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread.Sleep() in .Net 4.0. But, It will block the current thread.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: What about using System.Threading.Timer?? Can you share your idea??

Comment: As you just want to delay the method call, you don't need timer. You can use timer if you want to execute some task at specified intervals.

Answer (score -3):

Try using **Task.Delay**. You can use it like this:

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
DoSomething();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you explain why this one better than Timer.Tick??

Comment: I would suggest to use Timer if you have a block of code or a method that you want to execute continuously (i.e. execute method every 5 seconds). But, if you only need to delay something for a single time, I suggest you use Task.Delay. No setup needed, unlike Timer.

Comment: I have to call this method when the user press any key. So that, every time when the user press a key the method should be called with a short delay.

Comment: You'd have to setup the timer (configuring, creating an event, and starting it). Calling Task.Delay() is much simpler and less code. The performances aren't really that different. I just use timer whenever I want to continuously execute something.

Comment: Thank you so much for your concern. I'll try this.

Comment: Does Task.Delay(1000).Wait() work in .Net 4 and below frameworks??

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: What about using System.Threading.Timer?? Can you share your idea??